# What types of legal reasons may motivate online platforms to ban users who are found to have committed serious offences

Tags: criminal-law, any-jurisdiction

According to media reports, Theo Bertram, vice president of public policy Europe at TikTok, said his company is “committed to providing a space that embraces gender equity, supports healthy relationships, and respects intimate privacy” and bans accounts from people who have been found to have committed serious offences.

Why would a platform ban such users if use of the platform is not specified in for example the convicted user’s bail conditions or penal sentencing terms? I assume that associating or providing services to a convicted felon is not in any way illegal in itself.

It’s clearly the company’s own choice but why would they exercise it (almost certainly selectively for offences that interest cancel culture l which I think is mainly to say offences that bother sexual deviants or women)?

Answer (score 3):

Absent a statutory prohibition, a private platform may permit or refuse its services to anyone.

It is not prohibited for a private organization to discriminate, in the domain of accomodations, services, or facilities, on the basis of prior criminal convictions (B.C. [*Human Rights Code*](https://www.bclaws.gov.bc.ca/civix/document/id/complete/statreg/00_96210_01#section8)). And under the [*Canadian Human Rights Act*](https://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/acts/h-6/page-1.html#h-256801), discrimination in relation to a criminal conviction is only prohibited where it is in relation to a "conviction for an offence for which a pardon has been granted or in respect of which a record suspension has been ordered."

It would be pure speculation to guess what reasons might motivate someone to make a distinction in the provision of their services.

Comment: Great but I wasn’t asking what reasons there are not to discriminate or whether it is legally permitted to do so. It’s clearly the company’s own choice but why would they exercise it (almost certainly selectively for offences that interest cancel culture l which I think is mainly to say offences that bother sexual deviants or women)

Comment: Yes but one can usually still speculate intelligently. Nonetheless, the inclusion of the word might implies that one is seeking possible motivations in the forms of actually existing incentives, rather than the particular incentives that have actually motivated any given party.